# transforming derivatives yields: $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \frac{d}{dx} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \frac{d}{dy} = \frac{d}{dr}$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have been looking through my old university lectures and tried to reproduce a few of those.
What I found was the following:

Lets say we have a vector of functions $\left(h_1 \quad h_2 \quad h_3\right)$. They are formulated with respect to r and s, yet we are interested in the derivative with respect to $x$ and $y$.
Regarding that, I seem to have written down the following:

$$
    \left(\begin{matrix}
    \frac{d}{dx} \\
    \frac{d}{dy} \\
    \end{matrix}\right) \cdot \left(h_1 \quad h_2 \quad h_3\right) = J^{-1} \left(\begin{matrix}
    \frac{d}{dr} \\
    \frac{d}{ds} \\
    \end{matrix}\right) \cdot \left(h_1 \quad h_2 \quad h_3\right)
$$

with

$$
   J = \left(\begin{matrix}
    \frac{\partial x}{dr} & \frac{\partial y}{dr}\\
    \frac{\partial x}{dr} & \frac{\partial y}{ds}\\
    \end{matrix}\right)
$$.

I am wondering how one would correctly formulate/derive that.

Simplifying the stuff above, I would begin with:

$$
    J\cdot \left(\begin{matrix}
    \frac{d}{dx} \\
    \frac{d}{dy} \\
    \end{matrix}\right) =\left(\begin{matrix}
    \frac{d}{dr} \\
    \frac{d}{ds} \\
    \end{matrix}\right) 
$$

$$
    \left(\begin{matrix}
    \frac{\partial x}{dr} & \frac{\partial y}{dr}\\
    \frac{\partial x}{dr} & \frac{\partial y}{ds}\\
    \end{matrix}\right)\cdot \left(\begin{matrix}
    \frac{d}{dx} \\
    \frac{d}{dy} \\
    \end{matrix}\right) =\left(\begin{matrix}
    \frac{d}{dr} \\
    \frac{d}{ds} \\
    \end{matrix}\right) 
$$

If I look at the first row:

$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} \frac{d}{dx} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} \frac{d}{dy} = \frac{d}{dr}
$$

I dont see how that is supposed to be true.

I think I am getting confused with $\partial$ and $d$. Could someone here explain me how one would correctly formulate the things above and when to use $\partial$ and when to use $d$?

Greetings,
Finn

Comment: it is just the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)

Comment: I do know the chain rule but I am confused on how this is usually done with more than 1 variable

Comment: Also something does not seem to add up regarding partial and total derivatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to show it is using the Fréchet derivative. Let a diffeomorphism to $\mathbb{R} ^2$ given by $\varphi (r,s)=(\varphi_1(r,s),\varphi_2(r,s))=(x,y)$, and a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to Y$ for some banach space $Y$, then $\partial f(x,y)\hat x=\partial _1 f(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)$, using different notations, where $\hat x$ is the unit-length vector in $x$ direction, then

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(f\circ \varphi )(r,s)&=\partial _1(f\circ \varphi )(r,s)\\&=\partial (f\circ \varphi )(r,s)\hat r\\
&=(\partial f\circ \varphi )(r,s)\partial \varphi (r,s)\hat r \quad  \text{  here we used the chain rule }\\&=\partial f(x,y)\partial _1\varphi (r,s)\\&=\nabla f(x,y)\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\varphi (r,s)\\
&=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y),\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)\right)\cdot \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\varphi _1(r,s),\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\varphi _2(r,s)\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y),\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)\right)\cdot \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial r},\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\right)\\
&=\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)+\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)\\
&=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)f(x,y)
\end{align*}
$$

Therefore

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
$$
∎

Comment: You seem to only use partial derivatives. What is the difference if i may ask?

Comment: @FinnEggers in this context the "total derivative" is the Fréchet derivative, symbolized by the symbol $\partial $, every other is a partial derivative. The Fréchet derivative can be represented by the Jacobian matrix

Comment: Mhm. It makes sense what you did although I was hoping for a more simple explanation. I will accept it anyway. Thanks a lot! :)